# Invalid context 0x0 on UITextField (Xcode 5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, xcode5

I am using a UITextField in my app. I am using `[texfield becomeFirstResponder]`. This works just fine and loads the keyboard when the view is loaded. However, this error comes up when I click on the UITextField again after it has been brought up. I don't understand exactly why, but here is the output I am getting:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0.
CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. 
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0.
```

**Here is my code:**

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end


// ViewController.m
@synthesize textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: can you post some more code. ?

Comment: I mean I don't really know how much more source code I can add lol. Its pretty self-explanatory. I edited it though @Priyatham51

Comment: That's what is amazing about this bug. You can reproduce it with zero code--you don't even need the outlet to the text field. However, in order to reproduce the warning the text field does need to be completely empty when you double tap. Furthermore, this bug persists in iOS 7.0.3 both in the simulator and on a device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you've found an iOS bug (or at least a simulator bug). You can reproduce it even more simply:

- New Project (Single View)
- Drag UITextField onto Storyboard
- Run
- Click on UITextField.
- Click off of UITextField
- Click on UITextField
- (In some cases, you need to click off of UITextField again)
- Observe errors

I recommend opening a radar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought that this might be a simulator bug but was not sure. I just was scared that this app would be produced and then not work so I thought I would see what response I would get out of it on stack overflow. Can you explain what a radar is and I will do it.

Comment: Radar is the nickname for bugreport.apple.com. "A radar" is a defect opened on that system. (For your entertainment: the name "Radar" comes from the TV series MASH, which had a character of that name who always knew what you wanted before you even asked.)

Comment: @Zack have you filled this radar? I'm experiencing exactly the same.

Comment: Yes I have. @amb it actually came back as closed because of it being a duplicate. "Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed. 

The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title, state, product and rank."

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you are drawing some context on the screen . You need to write the code for drawing in the drawRect method . You mite have written the code elseWhere. Within the drawRect method make sure you check if the context exist as well .

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   if (context) {
        // Do your stuff
           }
```

Comment: If you literally copy & paste the source code I gave above into a new project with a UITextField in  the storyboard of Xcode 5 it will give you the error when you click the UITextField you've created.