# Are these IOS 7 bugs?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode5

I'm writing an app that simply provides a table view with editable custom cells with a text field, and when I enter edit mode to enter text in the cell, I get the following. However, NOT EVERY TIME I go in edit mode.

```
Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Jan 27 23:30:09 User-iMac.local SetList[5939] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

(truncated)

Comment: Yup it is, see this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469603/invalid-context-0x0-on-uitextfield-xcode-5

Comment: I don't think it's an iOS7 bug though... more so a bug in the new version of xCode... in my experience it only affects simulator.

Comment: Yes same question. I did google it before I posted.